# How to convert Wikipedia XML to HTML or PDF format?

Tags: java, html, pdf, wikipedia

I have a XML file which download it from Wikipedia database and it contains the Wikipedia articles.
Using Java, i want to convert them to PDF or Html format, how i can do that?

EDIT!!!!! :
I want to use mediawiki.

Comment: you might need this http://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use wikimodel and it do what I want, if anyone else want to do such a work i recommend wikimodel, like the code below:

```
public String getHTMLFormat() {
    WikiModel wikiModel = new WikiModel(
            "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${image}", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${title}");
    String htmlText = wikiModel.render(text);
    return htmlText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to lean `XSL` [Tranformation](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/), to convert XML to HTML.